# Android: Media Scanner won't scan m3u playlists?

Tags: java, android

I've written an audio player app through which users can create and save playlists (.m3u files) to external storage.

What I'm trying to do now is force update the mediastore content provider with new playlist files after they're created. This is so they'll show up in a "Load Playlist" dialog in the app which queries MediaStore for available playlists.

I've tried a number of methods to get MediaScanner to scan the newly created playlist but with no success - it won't show up in MediaStore query results...

```java
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
final File file = new File(root, CUSTOM_PLAYLISTS_DIR + "/" + filename);

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
out.write(songPaths.getBytes());
out.flush();
out.close();

// 1. using broadcast. Doesn't work
c.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
    Uri.fromFile(file)));

// 2. using MediaScannerConnection. Doesn't work
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(c,
            new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() },
            null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String s, Uri uri) {
                    Utils.log(this, "onScanCompleted s = " + s + ", uri = " + uri);
                }
            });

// 3. Sledgehammer approach - rescan entire external storage
// Doesn't work on KitKat! (permission denied)
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

However if I reboot the phone, the m3u file created by the app apparently is scanned because it will then show up in MediaStore results! (I take it this is equivalent to remounting external storage, as with method 3)

Any ideas how to get to this work on KitKat? I don't want to have to resort to manually writing playlist metadata to the MediaStore and having a "ghost" entry that has no corresponding file...

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @PradipPramanick unfortunately not

Comment: Wow, still no answers? I would like to know too.